# How to remove Set-Cookie header from Django response

Tags: python, django, cookies

I've created a middleware but there doesn't seem to be a Set-Cookie header in the response? But when testing the responses, its definitely there

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    "apps.base.middleware.RemoveHeadersMiddleware",
    ###
)

class RemoveHeadersMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # No Set-Cookie header here?????
        # del response._headers['Set-Cookie']
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The Set-Cookie header is somewhat magic, it is generated by Django based on the HTTPResponse's `cookie` attribute. You can remove the Set-Cookie header by  clearing `response.cookie` in a middleware that runs after any cookie-writing middlewares you may have. You probably don't want to do this for every request, but it can be useful for certain endpoints that may be highly cacheable.